# jquery UI datepicker transparent background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

This seems to be a common question but I've tried many answers but none of them have worked for me.

I'm using jquery UI datepicker. Something seems to be wrong. This is how I see it.

[image]

I've included the below in my file

- jquery-1.11.2.min.js
- jquery-ui.min.js (version 1.11.4)
- jquery-ui.min.css (version 1.11.4)

Also I've tried the below css but did not work.

```css
.ui-datepicker {
  background: #fff !important;
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

How do I make it look normal?

Comment: Is that the only CSS you have?

Comment: Yes, this is wrong... what is the order you load the js, the css?

Comment: @ZivWeissman: 'jquery-ui.min.css' --> head tags. the other two are at the end of the body tag.

Comment: @j08691. thanks. that's only jquery related css I'm loading.

Comment: And what is the order? make sure you load jquery before jquery ui

Also make sure you are not loading any jquery several times (can happen if u use bundles)

Comment: Is you page live somewhere where we can see it?

Comment: @ZivWeissman: yep, I'm loading `jquery-1.11.2.min.js` first and then `jquery-ui.min.js `. jquery is loaded once only.

Comment: What do you mean "jquery related css"? Any other CSS *could* be affecting the calendar. It all depends on what you have.

Comment: @j08691: thanks. I see your point. But if it's affecting the datepicker shouldn't the css be `.ui-datepicker{ .. something ...} `?

Comment: @DelightedD0D: thanks. sorry, it's not live.

Comment: Not necessarily. Any broad rules could be affecting it, especially anything table-centric. Can you reproduce the problem with a jsFiddle?

Comment: In chrome try right clicking on the element and selecting "inspect element" then look through the "styles" panel for any rules that might be causing this effect. You can uncheck them to see what happens if they were removed

Comment: Inspect the element using Firebug or developer tools and see which rules overrides yours.

Comment: @sebnukem: thanks. howcome `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css` this works. But when I copy and paste it in my local file the datepicker's NEXT and PREVIOUS buttons doesn't show?

Comment: @j08691: howcome when `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css` is used the datepicker works and if I copy and paste it in my local file the datepicker's NEXT and PREVIOUS buttons doesn't show?

Comment: I'd have to see a complete code example to tell you

Comment: @j08691: the issue was due to the missing `image` folder which come with the jquery.

Answer (score 7):

I set up a fiddle with the basic datepicker theme and a colored background (or transparent if you so wish): http://jsfiddle.net/uscmr3xo/3/

```
.ui-datepicker {
    /*background: transparent;*/
    background: blue;
}
```

It turned out "background" does the magic while "background-color" doesn't.
For some reasons theres no transparent BG in the jquery-ui ThemeRoller (http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). But if you want to use different color/styling schema please use the tool. Be careful customizing CSS to overwrite the default jquery-ui styles.